# xamarin is not working even after full installation

Tags: xamarin

After successful installation of xamarin, not able to start working on the project, showing the window, asking for Installation of xamarin again.

SDKs are already installed for android and ios

Comment: can you post more information about error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

If Your Not mention your system is MAC or Windows. If Windows. ,then please uninstall visualstudio and xamarin .then restat the machine and try again [Xamarin Download Docs](https://www.xamarin.com/download) . Note :(In Win 10 OS, keep Minimum 100GB space in C drive ).